# Firebase Import Error: Cannot use import statement outside module in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am working on a react project which is working on **react version 16.5.2**. Now, there is a requirement from client side to use Firebase for notification in application.

For this I have followed below tutorials:
https://blog.logrocket.com/push-notifications-react-firebase/

Now, when I run the project, I am getting this error:
`Cannot use import statement outside module`

When I debug the origin of error, I have found that this error is coming due to below line of code in firebase package:

```
import {registerVersion} from '@firebase/app'
```

I have tried to resolve the same by downgrading firebase npm version to 9.6.10 but still same error.
I have also tried by adding "**Type as module**" in package.json but in this case, my application is not running the command "npm run start" and throwing error in react-script start.js file.

Can someone please help me how can I solve this error? Thanks in advance.